# Where to store data permanently in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

When i store my windows-phone **application data** in **Isolated Storage**,will it be there even if my app is removed from the stack?

Comment: The quick answer is "yes"

Comment: Why didn't you try it before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data will be available on the device until you uninstall the application from your device